# Spark Scala error in filter while applying for loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]  val value = values.split( " " ).filter(x => ( for(y <- x) { if(y!=""){ y}}) )
```

My input RDD is like

```
1 : 11111,22222
2 : 22224 4747

val lines1 = input2.map( line => line.split(":") )

val l1 = lines1.flatMap( arr => {
val key = arr( 0 )
val values = arr( 1 )
val value = values.split( " " ).filter(x => ( for(y <- x) { if(y!=""){ y}}) )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you add input and expected output

Comment: Just a note that `y!=""` is `y.nonEmpty`.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` method requires a `boolean` *return type* checking a condition but your `filter` method seems its not returning anything as `for` loop is just creating `value` variable without returning anything at the end of `for` loop which *scala* assumes to be `unit`.

According to my understanding to your question, you are trying to `filter` the `empty` values from the second `array` of numbers. So if my understanding is correct then you can use the following logic

```
val lines1 = input2.map( line => line.split(":") )

val l1 = lines1.flatMap( arr => {
  val key = arr(0).trim
  val values = arr(1).trim
  val value = values.split(" ").map(x => x.filter(y => y != ""))
  value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` will return a Unit as it has no inherent output. Maybe you want a `for-comprehension`, but you would need to `yield` the result. Although even then the output would be a `Seq` and not the expected `Boolean`. I am guessing you want to filter your values down to only those that have a value. Without knowing the types it seems you could just use a filter via `filter(x=>x!="")` or maybe flatMap via `flatMap(x=>for{y<-x; y!=""}yield y)` but we need more info for a complete answer at this time.